# Cross compilation of C++ program which includes OpenCV header files fails

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake, raspberry-pi

I can cross compile a simple C++ program. (ex. `g++ -o test test.cpp & arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -o test test.cpp`).
But when I include OpenCV header files in a C++ program and cross compile it, it throws an error.(ex. `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -o ocv_test ocv_test.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv)`).

Also I can compile successfully with the default compiler i.e. g++.(ex. `g++ -o ocv_test ocv_test.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv)`)

I executed cmake with

```
-D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/linux/arm.toolchain.cmake \.
```

as per the opencv docs. That didn't help.

I added opencv include dir in compilation cmd ie `-I/path/to/opencv/include` and removing `pkg-config`. That didn't help.

I tried changing arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake by exporting `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` as per suggestion by someone. That didn't help.

I got the following error:

```
__/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_shape
//usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status__
```

I want my cross-compiled OpenCV app to run on a RaspberryPI.
*I'm confused. Cross compiling OpenCV sources with the `-D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` option should allow us to cross-compile OpenCV C++ programs. Otherwise we will have to cmake or make (cross-compile) every OpenCV C++ program seperately on a build machine.*

Comment: You need Linux ARM builds of all libraries you use. You usually need to cross-compile them yourself. So you need to cross-compile opencv as well as all libraries opencv itself depends on.

Comment: @NikosC. tried cross compile libraries that are required to cross-compile opencv c++ program by reading some tutorials on internet. but I couldn't do that. Then I just downloaded libraries of arm arch (.so files) and copied into /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/. Now this "//usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized" is gone. But now I'm getting "/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_aruco" errors like this. Please help.